# GraphQL and Spring Security using @PreAuthorize?

Tags: spring-security, graphql, graphql-spqr

I have a problem setting up spring security and disabling/enabling access to jwt-authenticated role-based users for  `graphql` services. All other `REST` endpoints are properly protected and `JWT` authentication and role-based authorization are working correctly.

What I have so far:

In my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class, I have following code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable().cors()
                         .and()
                         .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**/student-service/auth/**").permitAll().antMatchers("**/student-service/auth/**").authenticated()
                         .and()
                         .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "**/graphql/**").permitAll().antMatchers("**/graphql/**").authenticated()
                         .and()
                         .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.headers().cacheControl();

}
```

And on `graphql` service, I have a `@PreAuthorize`:

```java
@Component 
public class UserResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver{
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepo repo;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')")
    public User findUser(int id) {
        return User.builder()
                    .id(1)
                   .email("test@grr.la")
                   .password("123")
                   .username("John")
                   .bankAccount(BankAccount.builder()
                                            .id(1)
                                            .accountName("some account name")
                                            .accountNumber("some account number")
                                            .build())
                    .build();
    }
}
```

After getting JWT on `localhost:8080/login` and sending `graphql` query, with above configuration and code, I got:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:238) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:58) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
```

This is how request looks like from `Postman`:

[image]

GraphQL query:

```
query {
  findUser(id : 1) {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

And response:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Access is denied",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 1
                }
            ],
            "path": [
                "findUser"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "type": "AccessDeniedException",
                "classification": "DataFetchingException"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "findUser": null
    }
}
```

`application.yml` file:

```yaml
graphql:
  servlet:
    max-query-depth: 100
    exception-handlers-enabled: true
  playground:
    headers:
      Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
```

`query.graphqls` file:

```
type Query {
    
    findUser(id: ID): User
    
}

type User {
    
    id: ID!
    username: String
    password: String
    email: String
    bankAccount: BankAccount
}

type BankAccount {
    id: ID!
    accountName: String
    accountNumber: String
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent a day trying to figure this out.  In your data fetching environment if you invoke a call to

```java
environment.getContext()
```

You should get back an instance of *GraphQLContext* which has the HTTP request and headers with the authorization.  For me this was essentially an empty *HashMap* with no details about the request.  After digging around and trying everything from AOP changes, I found a suggestion from auth0 to make a class that implements *GraphQLInvocation*.  Here is my solution which places an instance of Spring Security context into the data fetching environment context object.  I'm at least able to authenticate the data fetchers now since I have a Spring Security context to work with (with granted authorities and such.)  I'd rather have a filter integrated with Spring Security (and I can get preAuthorize methods working like you are doing), but I'm rolling with this for the time for now.

```java
@Primary
@Component
@Internal
public class SecurityContextGraphQLInvocation implements GraphQLInvocation {

    private final GraphQL graphQL;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public SecurityContextGraphQLInvocation(GraphQL graphQL, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.graphQL = graphQL;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> invoke(GraphQLInvocationData invocationData, WebRequest webRequest) {
        final String header = webRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        SecurityContext securityContext;
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
        } else {
            String authToken = header.substring(7);
            JwtAuthenticationToken authRequest = new JwtAuthenticationToken(authToken);
            final var authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
            securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl(authentication);
        }

        ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(invocationData.getQuery())
                .context(securityContext)
                .operationName(invocationData.getOperationName())
                .variables(invocationData.getVariables())
                .build();
        return graphQL.executeAsync(executionInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thank you for putting time and effort investigating about problem I had. Unfortunately, because of my job obligations I'm not sure when I'll be able to give detail answer on this question. I remember that I had found the right solution and also I switched to Graphql SPQR library which comes as a spring starter dependency.